# Crashing Issue on iOS7 Titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium-mobile

I am working in Titanium Mobile.
I ran into a problem. I developed an application for iPhone. It was working perfectly over iOS6 but now having some crashing issues over iOS7 :(. Have googled it but got no clue whatsoever :(
My Trace log is :

```
 [ERROR] The application has crashed with an uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'.
 Reason: 
 *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 29 beyond bounds [0 .. 28] 
 Stack trace:
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x043ab5c8 __exceptionPreprocess + 152
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03eb58b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0434c4e6 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 246
 3   SpotLight                           0x0007c9b0 -[TiViewProxy insertSubview:forProxy:] + 1520
 4   SpotLight                           0x0007d22b -[TiViewProxy relayout] + 2075
 5   SpotLight                           0x0007bcd3 -[TiViewProxy refreshView:] + 675
 6   SpotLight                           0x0007d543 -[TiViewProxy layoutChildrenIfNeeded] + 259
 7   SpotLight                           0x001faba7 +[TiLayoutQueue layoutProxy:] + 87
 8   SpotLight                           0x001fa972 performLayoutRefresh + 530
 9   CoreFoundation                      0x04369bd6      
 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
10  CoreFoundation                      0x043695bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
11  CoreFoundation                      0x04351628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
12  CoreFoundation                      0x04350ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
13  CoreFoundation                      0x043508db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
14  GraphicsServices                    0x046059e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
15  GraphicsServices                    0x04605809 GSEventRun + 104    

16  UIKit                               0x01b5fd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
17  SpotLight                           0x000042a8 main + 456
18  SpotLight                           0x00002bf5 start + 53
19  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Someone has any clue about it.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the address of array that is not exist. Your array has data between range 0 to 28 index and you are trying to access the data at index 29. please check data in your. Try to count the array index. Please write some snippet , so that i can find exact issue.

Comment: Well as far as my arrays are concerned there no single array with index more than 5 so how this can happen that it is trying to access the 29th index :( And same time it is working quite well on iOS6. :( –

Comment: Here you go with code snippet http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/159323/ios7-crashing-issue#comment-193985

Comment: u there Smith ?? did you got any clue ?? @Smith

Comment: No clue at all, Sorry:(